# Why does Agra have cows on most roads and public areas whereas Delhi does not?

Tags: india, culture, new-delhi, agra

So I visited Agra the other day and there were cows everywhere. On the side of the road, on the road and in one case sleeping on the road. Meanwhile in Delhi, this isn't the case.

Are they there and I just haven't seen them or is there a particular reason why Delhi doesn't have them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Delhi is a Modern Indian city with a population of about 15 million people. If you have been to Delhi, you must have noticed the amount of traffic in the city. Even though it is true that cows are worshiped in Hindu Mythology, they are an inconvenience for the flow of traffic. Over time they have been moved away from Delhi and now you won't find them on most roads. If you go into the village sections of Delhi, you will still find them in many households but this practice is also decreasing due to unavailability of grazing land. 15 years ago, Delhi had much more cows than now.

Agra is a relatively older city which is much less developed. It is not only smaller than Delhi but it more traditional that it. There is a good availability of grazing lands near Agra so you will still find many cows on the street even though they are an inconvenience to traffic.

Official removal efforts were also made in Delhi in order to prevent Cows and Buffalo within the city center. Conscious efforts by citizens were also made in order to prevent deaths of Cows. Traffic usually waits when cows are crossing roads as a mark of respect but every once in a while some lunatic crashes into one. It's simply a step into modernization and reducing inconveniences to both kinds of species.

Everything else apart, I was born and brought up in Delhi and have visited Agra several times as well. I truly cherish both cities and find that each has its own beauty. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wish it were so in Mumbai another modern city. I happen to see cows quite often.

Comment: @One-One - Unfortunately I haven't got the chance to visit Mumbai but I would believe that Mumbai still suffers from this problem due to slow moving traffic and lesser road infrastructure than Delhi in terms of intercity highways. The Delhi Metro construction in Delhi has also greatly helped reduce this problem by easing the flow of on-road traffic.

Comment: "as a mark of respect" ... this sounds funny. nobody wants to bump into anyone by choice, same with cows. Not a mark of respect to me.

Comment: @fotuzlab Mark of respect as in people simply wait, they do not try to move the cows. If there would be dogs, police would scare them away, but this is not done in the case of cows.

Comment: I don't know about mark of respect – when I am driving I stay well away from cows and suchlike mainly because I feel they might be unpredictable and damage my vehicle if provoked.

Answer (score 6):

The cows you see are not strays. They are owned by somebody, who lets them loose during the day to feed (which they probably get in the city markets and the open trash that lies all around, in most Indian towns and cities), without having to pay for cattle feed. At night, the owner just waits for the cows to come home. Or he doesn't. They come home anyway.

Animals freely roaming about in public places are a hazard to themselves and to others. The owners in larger cities try to keep them chained up for their own safety as the other person here pointed out. The smaller ones don't have enough traffic.

Comment: Does Agra not have enough traffic?